# How do I make libpcap/pcap_loop non-blocking?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, libpcap, packet-sniffers

I'm currently using libpcap to sniff traffic in promiscuous mode

```
int main() 
{
    // some stuff
    printf("Opening device: %s\n", devname.c_str());

    handle = pcap_open_live(devname.c_str(), 65536 , 1 , 0 , errbuf);

    if (handle == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open device %s : %s..." , devname.c_str(), errbuf);
        return 1;
    }
    printf(" Done\n");

    pcap_loop(handle , -1 , process_packet , NULL);
    // here run a thread to do some stuff. however, pcap_loop is blocking
    return 0;
}
```

I'd like to add an external thread to do some other stuff. How do I change the code above to make it non-blocking?

Comment: Start the thread before you call pcap_loop?

Comment: I can try, but what if I wanted to do some other stuff after pcap_loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use non-blocking mode on libpcap you have to use pcap_dispatch, but note, `pcap_dispatch` can work in blocking or in non-blocking mode, it depends how you set libpcap, to set libpcap to work in non-blocking you have use the function `pcap_setnonblock`:

```
int pcap_setnonblock(pcap_t *p, int nonblock, char *errbuf);
```

The difference between blocking and non-blocking is not a loop that runs forever, but in blocking the function `pcap_dispatch` waits for a packet and only returns when this packet is received, however, in the non-blocking mode the function returns immediately and the callback must process the packet.

> In "non-blocking" mode, an attempt to read from the capture
>   descriptor with pcap_dispatch() will, if no packets are currently
>   available to be read, return 0 immediately rather than blocking
>   waiting for packets to arrive. pcap_loop() and pcap_next() will not
>   work in "non-blocking" mode.

http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap_setnonblock.3pcap.html

Answer (score 0):

pcap_loop is meant to go on until all input ends.  If you don't want that behavior, call pcap_dispatch in a loop instead.  By definition pcap_loop will never return, its meant to  always searching for more data.

Comment: thank you. for now I run the thread before pcap_loop. it seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

I use `pcap_next_ex` It returns a result indicating if a packet was read. This way I manage the acquisition my own thread. See an example [here](https://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_40_2/html/group__wpcap__tut4.html). The `read_timeout` in `pcap_open` also affects this function.